# Jquery animate callback firing to soon

Tags: jquery, callback, jquery-animate

I have a simple jquery animation where i'm experimenting with. Its a sort of slot machine with just 2 containers.

What im trying to create is that when you click a button(container A is in screen, static): Container A slides upward into the screen with container B following. Then when the animation is finished. I want to reset container A's position.

I currently have it set up like:

CSS:

```
.containerA { position: fixed; top: 0; width:200px; height: 100vh; }
.containerB { position: fixed; top: 100vh; width: 200px; height: 100vh; }
```

Jquery:

```
$("#containerBtrigger").click(function(){
// set z-index first so you wont see container A resetting position.
  $(".containerB").css("z-index", "20");
  $(".containerA").css("z-index", "0");

//have container B slide upwards into the screen
$(".containerB").animate({
  top : "0",}, 500);

//container A slides upwards, out of the screen, when its animation is done, it should set the position to 100vh, out of the viewport.
$('.containerA').animate({
  top: '-100vh'
  }, 500, function () {
     $(this).css({ top : '100vh' }); });
});
```

However, whenever i click the triggering button, the container that should slide out of the screen, slides downwards, while the other slides upwards as supposed to.

I have also tried replacing the callback function of animate with:

```
function () { $(this).removeAttr('style');
```

But this doens't make a difference either.

I am still very bad with jQuery and haven't touched in months. 
There is probably a way better way to make this slotmachine setup, but at this point i am absolutely clueless.

**EDIT:** I just saw that it moves up for like 3px and then slides down

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery looks ok to me, but it's impossible to say since I can't see how you structured your HTML, which is important. Always do your best to provide ALL relevant code in you qustions.

You don't really need to worry about z-index if the elements are siblings. Scroll them both upward at the same pace, then at the end, check if the box is above the frame (or window) and if it is, just reset it's css so it's below. jQuery's `.css()` functoin is instant, so your users wont see it going back to the bottom.

**[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/h1x97uye/2/)**

```
<style>
    .frame { 
        height: 200px; 
        width: 200px;
        border: 5px solid gray; 
        margin: 20px; 
        position: relative; 
        background-color: pink; 
        float: left; 
        overflow: hidden; /* uncomment to see full action */
    }
    .frame > div {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        left: 0; 
        height: 200px; 
        width: 200px; 
    }
    .box_a {
        top: 0; 
        background-color: red; 
    }
    .box_b {
        top: 200px; 
        background-color: blue; 
    }
    #scroll { 
        float: left;
        margin: 20px 0 0 50px; 
    }
</style>

<div class="frame">
    <div class="box_a"></div>
    <div class="box_b"></div>
</div>
<button id="scroll" type="button">Scroll</button>

<script>
// when called, collect all boxes
// use current "top" value to calculate new "top" value
// animate it, then check new "top" to see if it's above the frame
// if so, instantly reset it to the bottom. 
const scroll_all_boxes = function() {
    $('.box_a, .box_b').each(function(index, box) {
        const old_top = parseInt($(box).css('top')); // example: '200px' => 200
        const new_top = old_top - 200 + 'px';  // example: "-200px"

        $(box).animate({
            top: new_top
        }, 500, function() {
            // after animation, if box is at above frame
            // reset css so it's at bottom, instantly 
            const postAnimationTop = parseInt($(box).css('top')); // '200px' => 200
            if (postAnimationTop !== 0) {
                $(box).css({
                    top: '200px'
                });
            }
        });
    });
}

$('#scroll').click(scroll_all_boxes);
</script>
```

The script above is not a copy/paste solution, but it's a great simple example. Ask me questions if you need to, but do your best to examine it, and apply it to your own situation. That's the best way to learn. Good luck!

Comment: Hey, amazing reply with a load of in-depth information. I have been studying the code for some hours since you posted and it gave me some insights on how to rewrite the code.

To be honest, im still struggling very much. I have pasted your code into my website and made adjustments where needed. The biggest problem im having is that i am using 2 buttons to call the boxes into the screen. 

It makes it really hard for me to edit your small tutorial, and since im teaching myself, and my field of work is not development im not going anywhere tbh. im trying to implement it at: chrisholstein.nl

Comment: The best thing to do is try to _isolate the problem_. Then open a site like JS Fiddle and try to create a small demo that demonstrates the issue. Not the whole website, just the one problem, with the one feature. Then post that HTML, CSS, and JS here, and ask a question about the specific issue itself. The better your example code is, the more likely you are to find someone to help debug your exact code. Good luck!